# Visual Studio 2010 Intellisense Breaks after Deploying to Sharepoint Site

Tags: visual-studio, development

I've ran in to this in two completely different environments now. I can build the solution and not have any problems with intellisense. If I deploy our Web Parts project to my local SharePoint 2010 site, as soon as the deployment process hits 'Deploy Succeeded', intellisense blows up, and I get compile errors on the current page. I can go and select each project in the solution, click refresh, and everything is good again.

Any ideas? Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially I thought It's not Intellisense by itself, but the reference for Microsoft.SharePoint.dll that are lost (maybe references to projects as well).

I've seen such behavior, but adding the reference back seemed more appropriate than a thorough research at the moment.

In the comments below guys make it clear that exactly the Intellisense symbols are lost.

Comment: I've seen this, but not the reference itself dropping off, just the symbols for intellisense. A rebuild of the project after deploying fixes it for me (temporarily).

Comment: James, that's exactly what is happening. The symbols are gone. Refreshing each of the projects brings it back for me.

Comment: Is there a post build event I can create on the web parts project to refresh each of my other projects to prevent this? It's very irritating with multiple deployments.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it appears it is currently only a manual process